# How to save a selected item from an array adapter to a string

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

So i select a value from the list but i want to save the selected value to a string. how can i do that?

```
public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView (Android.Views.LayoutInflater inflater, Android.Views.ViewGroup container, Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment1, container, false);

        PickUpDates = new DateTime[]
        {

            DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*2),
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*3), DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*4),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*8),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*9),
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*10),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*11),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*12),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*13),
            DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*14),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*15),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*16),DateTime.Now.AddDays(1*17),
        };

        Spinner PUDspinner = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.pickupDateSpinner);
        PUDspinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(PUDSPinner_ItemSelected);

        var pickUpCustomDatesList = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            pickUpCustomDatesList.Add(PickUpDates[i].ToString("ddd, MMM dd"));

        }

        var pickupDateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem, pickUpCustomDatesList);
        PUDspinner.Adapter = pickupDateAdapter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [Spinner example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/spinner/):

```
private void PUDSPinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
{
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)sender;

    var item = spinner.GetItemAtPosition (e.Position);
    string selected = item.ToString();
}
```

Comment: how can i access the string out of this method?

Comment: if you want to access the value from elsewhere in the code, assign it to a class level variable